# Was Luke Skywalker technically a deserter in ESB?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

After re-watching *The Empire Strikes Back* after many years, I noticed that as Luke flies away from Hoth, he says to someone (probably Wedge Antilles)

> I'll meet you at the rendezvous point

Or something like that (I might be confusing the words from when he tells Lando he'll meet him on Tatooine, but he definitely said something like that). Even in Princess Leia's briefing to the fighter pilots escorting the transports:

> When you've gotten past the energy shield, proceed directly to the
>   rendezvous point.

It doesn't sound like there's any room for interpretation there. The fighters are to head straight for the rendezvous point as soon as they're clear of the Imperial blockade. Even R2-D2 is under the impression that Luke's orders are to proceed to the Alliance's regroup point, and is surprised when Luke tells him they're headed to the Dagobah system.

Was Luke technically AWOL? Is there any canon evidence that can clear him of the charge of desertion (with Alliance equipment, no less)? Did he get clearance from *anyone at all* to go to Dagobah?

Comment: In theory, Luke could have led the Empire straight to Yoda, whose location is a highly classified secret. The defence that Kenobi's ghost told him to do it might not have impressed a court martial.

Comment: Now I think of it, Luke could always fall back on Jedi skills. LUKE: You don't want to press charges against me. ALLIANCE OFFICER: I don't want to press charges against you. LUKE: You want to give me another medal. ALLIANCE OFFICER: I want to give you another medal.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit: Luke states in *Shadows of the Empire* that Rebels have minds too strong for his mind tricks. Still, thumbs up for the laughs!

Comment: @James Sheridan: Thanks. I thought that might be the case, which is why it's a comment and not an answer. :-)

Comment: Since we now have an answer that is consistent with Star Wars canon, you may wish to consider your acceptance of the earlier answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is covered in the film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_%28novel%29). As a Commander in the Rebel Alliance, his rank evidently to grants him the authority to countermand orders as he sees fit, presumably with the proviso that the new orders are still in the best interest of the Alliance's larger goals.

> Artoo then gently beeped a reminder about Princess Leia’s order.
>   Exasperated, the young pilot exclaimed, “I’m countermanding that
>   order! Now, be still.”
>
> The little droid fell silent. **Luke was, after all, a commander in the
>   Rebel Alliance and, as such, could countermand orders.** He was making a
>   few minor adjustments on the controls when Artoo chirped up again.

Answer (score 21):

Luke Skywalker never received clearance to go to Dagobah, no. The Rebel Alliance, however, had a far looser command hierarchy than the Empire, with a strong emphasis on individual initiative. In the *New Jedi Order* series, Luke Skywalker is confronted by a candidate for the New Republic Presidency who quotes Luke's own service record to him, noting the absence after Hoth is listed as "pursuing spiritual studies."

There is no mention that Luke was officially AWOL during this period, so it would seem that he was not, though there is no definitive statement in canon. In a regular military, he would certainly be considered AWOL, or at least MIA. We must also bear in mind that, unlike the fighter pilots you mentioned, Luke Skywalker is never directly ordered to go to the rendezvous point while onscreen, so he could have some wiggle room in his orders that they do not. Regardless, he seems to have been AWOL in practice, though not in a legal sense.

Comment: Individual initiative or not, there is no military force in the world that would let a pilot abscond with the equivalent of an X-Wing for a private spiritual retreat lasting weeks or months, without facing severe consequences. That said, Luke is the hero who destroyed the first Death Star and Leia could have helped make any charges go away, especially if she presented it as Luke rescuing her instead of the other way around.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit Of course, Star Wars doesn't take place on this world, but in a galaxy far, far away...

Comment: @evilsoup Luke can tell that to the court martial.

Comment: A lot of non-canon material cited in this example! ;)

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit: It is explicitly stated by the New Rep politician in the aforementioned *NJO* novel - I believe it was *Destiny's Way*, but I no longer own the series to check - that Luke's actions would be considered "going AWOL, and misappropriation of military hardware to boot" by that point, which is between 25-30 years after *ANH*. This would imply, however, that his actions were not considered to be "going AWOL" **at the time**. Military legalities, in other words, changed in the meantime. This is explicitly stated in *Shield of Lies*, when Admiral Ackbar argues with a recruiter.

Comment: @JamesSheridan: If the Rebel Alliance had *any rules at all*, you'd think that borrowing an X-Wing for a month would violate them. (Not to mention that it must have needed some serious maintenance after being buried in a swamp.) But between Luke's hero status and Leia's influence, I expect his absence could have been quietly ignored, or explained away *post hoc* as a special mission.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit: Kenobi was a General. Luke could easily have claimed to be following the orders of a superior officer. Kenobi may not have outranked Rieekan, but he definitely had more seniority.

Comment: @JamesSheridan: Kenobi was *dead*. Following his orders is only a reasonable excuse if Luke can convince the Alliance he is in communication with Kenobi's ghost. Short of Kenobi materialising in front of a tribunal to testify on Luke's behalf, this might be difficult. Also, AFAIK Kenobi never held any official position in the Rebel Alliance; his rank of General was in the Grand Army of the Republic, which of course became the Empire.

Comment: It's weird, given his status in the Alliance, that he didn't just ask for time off and permission to borrow the X-wing. Given his achievements, I think there's very little question that it would have been granted. Anyway, I was hoping that the ESB novelization or some other canon source mentioned in passing that he had done this. Chalk it up to Luke's youthful impatience I guess.

Comment: @Jayraj: If Luke wanted to borrow an X-Wing, the Rebel leaders would want to know why. If he said the ghost of Obi-Wan Kenobi had told him to seek out a mysterious Jedi Master named Yoda, it would sound more than a little crazy, so I can see why he just took off without asking. (Some rebels would know of Yoda's history and maybe even his location, but Luke is *not* aware of this -- it is pretty clear he has never heard of Yoda before receiving Kenobi's instructions.)

Comment: If Yoda is truly in a "highly classified" location, would people really say "see you after you go train with Yoda!" as he is leaving?  It is entirely feasible that he was following classified orders, that would not show up on his record even later, which would account for no action ever being taken.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit, I forget what EU book, but I thought I recalled one of them mentioning that the Rebels actually gifted the X-Wing to Luke after Yavin as a reward.   So he wasn't borrowing an X-Wing, he was flying his own.

Comment: @Zordache: I actually remember reading something similar in passing, to be honest. Like you, I don't recall in what source though. He certainly still uses his X-Wing for private use in *The Thrawn Trilogy*, despite having resigned from the military.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit: Given that many Rebels had already met Jedi in the past, convincing a tribunal that he'd received orders from General Kenobi - who was present when Mon Mothma and Bail Organa first discussed armed resistance to Palpatine, in a deleted scene from *Revenge of the Sith* - might not be nearly as difficult as you think.

Comment: @JamesSheridan: The rebels had met Jedi, but not Force ghosts. At the end of Ep3, Obi-Wan was astonished to learn about Qui-Gon's ghost. If a Jedi Master didn't know about them, they would hardly have been common knowledge among non-Jedi. I still think the Rebel leadership (who for the most part are hardened soldiers who have spent the last 20 years fighting a guerrilla war) would be a bit skeptical of "the ghost told me to do it".

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit: How many people know the slightest bit about Jedi abilities? If Luke presented his arguments well, he could pull it off. Of course, he wasn't court-martialed, so this whole discussion is mute.

Comment: @JamesSheridan: Yes, agreed. When Luke didn't appear at the rendezvous, the Rebel leaders would have assumed he had been killed, or chased off in another direction like the *Millennium Falcon*. When Luke reappeared after Bespin, they would have been glad to see him, but he would have still had some explaining to do. Technically he might have broken the rules, and they could have court-martialled him if they wanted to, but after a demonstration of his new-found Jedi powers they would probably have been happy to forget about the whole issue (without any need to mention ghosts).

Comment: Going into the old EU (Legends) a bit: in Heir to the Empire by Timothy Zahn, specific mention is made that Leia has official support from the New Republic for pursuing her Jedi training, provided it does not interfere with her other duties. Additionally, members of the Alliance frequently said "may The Force be with you", indicating they supported the Jedi. It is possible that since Luke was force-sensitive, his training was important to his duties, and as such he was given some leeway to pursue it -- especially when the Alliance would be busy fleeing Hoth and avoiding detection anyway.

Comment: @Jayraj - regarding Luke "borrowing" an X-Wing, it is possible that he was gifted an X-Wing by the Alliance in lieu of meaningful pay or other financial bonus as a reward for his actions at the Battle of Yavin. It is mentioned in the old EU (Legends) that he owns his own X-Wing, which is what gives me this idea.

Answer (score 5):

Considering he's the only known person who could fight Vader, I think the Rebel Alliance would accept his trip to Dagobah. Firepower wasn't working for the last 20 years.

Comment: In the novel I mentioned in my own answer, Luke's political enemy outright mentions that he accepts "the necessity of your actions," while simultaneously saying he'd have Luke shot if he tried that sort of thing under his command. So you're not wrong about the Rebels being desperate enough to turn a blind eye to Luke stretching the rules.