# Did the others know when Luke went to Dagobah to train with Yoda?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

My memory is a bit fuzzy, but if I remember correctly Luke was supposed to go to the rendezvous point with R2-D2 after they were attacked on Hoth. Luke tells the other rebels he will meet them at the rendezvous point as well.

However once he gets in his ship he changes course to go to Dagobah where (if I understood the story correctly) he spends months, with no communication with the rest of the rebels, training with Yoda.

Did anybody know he had gone to Dagobah? Did anybody even know he was missing? Why didn't the rebels go looking for him?

Comment: Partial duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59907/was-luke-skywalker-technically-a-deserter-in-es

Comment: Regarding going looking for him... Space is big.  The rebels might have checked a few obvious places (ie: Tatooine) but they hardly have the time or manpower to mount a galaxy-wide search for one guy, no matter how important he may be to their cause.

Answer (score 3):

The very short answer is that **nobody in the Rebellion knew that Luke had gone to Dagobah**. His decision to go was completely unexpected and the one person who might have been able to tell them where he'd gone (Han) was otherwise detained with his hyperdrive problems and impromptu trip to Cloud City.

Had Han and Leia successfully rendezvoused with the Rebel fleet without incident, they might have gone to find Luke before their attack on the Death Star II. This assumes that Han remembered the name of the system, was able to find it on his star charts and was somehow about to locate Luke's X-Wing on Dagobah.

Comment: So both luke and leia fail to show up at the rendezvous point and no one even notices? I thought they were more important than that

Comment: @user13267 - Everyone scattered. I'm sure they noticed her absence and we're sad that she was probably dead, but the Rebellion is bigger than any one individual.

Answer (score 0):

Since the story doesn't follow the Rebel Alliance as a whole, we have no way of knowing what search efforts they may have mounted to find Luke.

Our only other point of view is Han and Leia's efforts to evade being captured after leaving Hoth and their stay on Cloud City and they never made it to the rendezvous either. We can't know what the Rebel Alliance thought of Luke's disappearance (or Han and Leia's for that matter). The escape from Hoth was hectic and dangerous. They might have assumed he was captured or killed. The same goes for Han and Leia.

It wasn't until after they all left Cloud City that they were finally able to make their way to the rendezvous together.

On a side note, I don't believe Luke spent months on Dagobah. I'd say weeks at most. The two story lines are taking place at the same time and there's no way Han and Leia spent months running from the Star Destroyer or traveling to Bespin or being tortured by Vader. This question deals with that more in depth...

[How long was Luke Skywalker's training with Yoda?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13776/how-long-was-luke-skywalkers-training-with-yoda)